# iOS - How to implement self created delegate in ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

i have created a delegate for my project the code of my main view is

**VedantViewController.h**

```
@protocol VedantDelegate;

@interface VedantViewController : UIViewController
{    
    id <VedantDelegate> delegate;   
}

//some other outlets
@property(nonatomic, assign) id <VedantDelegate> delegate;

@protocol VedantDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)display:(NSString *)JSONResponse;

@end
```

**VedantViewController.m**

```
@synthesize delegate;

[delegate display:jsonResponse];
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<VedantDelegate>

- (void)display:(NSString *)JSONResponse;
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
- (void)display:(NSString *)string
{

}
```

but this code is not working properly
when i debug the code using breakpoints the code reaches the

```
[delegate display:abc];
```

but it does not calls display function in **SecondViewController.m** file

i think my code is right but some mistake that i can't recognize

let me explain you the flow of my project this could be the problem

by default the VedantViewController view is launched 
after that when the show button is click it calls the SecondViewController view in the view these is list button that calls the function in VedantViewController this function then calls the delegate method that is [delegate display:jsonResponse];

Thanks in Advance,
Arun.

Answer (score 0):

The view controller which is confirming with the protocol, should have this line in the viewDidLoad or anywhere you are making the object of that viewController

Add this line in SecondViewController.m

`VedantViewControllerObject.delegate = self;`

Comment: Are you creating the object of VedantViewController ?

Comment: property delegate not found on object of type VedantViewController

Comment: yes, I am creating an object of VedantViewController in SecondViewController

Comment: Are you importing VedantViewController.h in SecondViewController?

Comment: Please check the function names, As other guys are saying You added displayAccounts method in delegate and calling display method, that can cause issues. If that methods are not implemented in the delegate class.

Answer (score 0):

```
@protocol VedantDelegate;

    @interface VedantViewController : UIViewController{


        id<VedantDelegate> delegate;

    }
     //some other outlets
    @property(nonatomic,assign) id<VedantDelegate> delegate;

    @protocol VedantDelegate <NSObject>

    -(void)displayAccounts:(NSString *)JSONResponse;
    -(void)display:(NSString *)JSONResponse;

@end
```

and also set delegate to object of  VedantViewControllerObject class as self in SecondViewController class and the object of VedantViewControllerObject class should be initialized and allocated.

```
vedantViewControllerObject.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `VedantViewController.h` file you declared method as below

```
-(void)displayAccounts:(NSString *)JSONResponse;
```

But you are calling it `[delegate display:jsonResponse];`

You just try to call

```
 [delegate displayAccounts:jsonResponse];
```

And in **SecondViewController.m**

```
(void)displayAccounts:(NSString *)string{

    }
```

Comment: yeah it's the same funtion i typed it by mistake, sorry

Comment: did you allocate VedantViewController class befor calling delegate method

Comment: Instead of @property(nonatomic,assign) id<VedantDelegate> delegate; you just use @property(nonatomic,strong) id<VedantDelegate> delegate;  i am not sure whether it will work or not but try it

Comment: You just log viewcontroller delegate you can check whether its nil or not

Comment: And also you set delegate like this self.obj.delegate = self;

Comment: so its becomes nil that is the problem are you using xib

Comment: self.VedantViewControllerobj.delegate = self this shows error

Comment: you have set property for VedantViewControllerobj and you need to synthesis it

Comment: i am creating the object directly in SecondViewController.m like VedantViewController *vedant; after @synthesis code

Comment: did you connect the outlet to the view in interface builder.

Comment: i tried this VedantViewController *vedant; in .h and synthesisin .m file but still prints null in console log

Comment: once you try without using xib

Comment: did you connect VedantViewController view in xib

Comment: access VedantViewController like this [self.delegate displayAccounts:jsonResponse];

Comment: dd you get any warning like this instance method was not found.

Comment: No,i don't have any warning

Comment: self.obj.delegate = self; i tried this it prints some value but the delegate method is not fired

Comment: access whole delegate by using self

Answer (score 0):

There  are some issues in your code:

1. set the delegate in second view controller
    vedViewObject.delegate = self;
2. You added `displayAccounts` method in delegate and calling `display` method, that can cause issues. If that methods are not implemented in the delegate class.
3. Add if condition like: `if(delegate)[delegate displayAccounts:jsonResponse];`